# Retrofit removes query parameters from base url

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have query parameters that is used for all requests. It is added to the base url as follow

```
private val baseUrl = HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .host("ws.audioscrobbler.com")
            .addPathSegment("2.0")
            .addPathSegment("")
            .addQueryParameter("format", "json")
            .addQueryParameter("api_key", "val")
            .build()

retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
```

The api service call is

```
 @GET("./")
    fun searchTracks(@Query("otherParam") query: String): Call<Any>
```

The url is built correctly till the actual call is made. It removes the query params added in the base url and keeps only the one added in service call. 
Shown in debugging till the `delegate.enqueue()` is called in `ExecutorCallAdapterFactory`:"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?format=json&api_key=val&otherParam=val" 
shown in logs (via interceptor): "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?otherParam=val"

Any idea why this happens and how to keep the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add query parameters to url in request interceptor.

```
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =  
    new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();
        HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.url();

        HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("format", "json")
                .addQueryParameter("api_key", "val")
                .build();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .url(url);

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```